# In Java, how can I make a public variable in one class visible to methods in another class within an imported package?

Tags: java

In a scientific programming application, I have a class (class1) that takes an input of an integer (k) from another program. I initialized k publicly. Inside class1 I run some commands and set that integer. I have another class (class2) that lies within a package (imported in the first class). **I want to retrieve the value of k that was set in class1 and use it in class2.task3.**

Currently, I am retrieving that k value by passing it as an argument through every method on the way to class2 so that I can use it in class2.task3. *I tried passing k as an argument into ONLY task3, without making it an argument of task1 and task2, and the program compiled, but the value of k was not up to date once it got to task3 (stayed stuck at 101 instead of updating to 102 or another value)*. I also tried and cannot import class1 to the package.

**What is a better way to do this?** I have passed variables other than k to class2 in the same way. It works, but there is probably an elegant solution that I am missing.

Here is an outline of class1 as relevant to this problem, located(in eclipse) as src > (default package) > class1.java :

```
import package.class2;

public class1 test {

    public int k = 101; // initialize k 

    public void run(String arg) {

        // update value of k, , retrieved externally
        int k=102; // or any integer
        task1(k);
    }

    public void task1(int k) {

       task2(k);

    }

    public void task2(int k) {

       class2.task3(k);

    }

} // end class
```

Here is class2, in src > package > class2.java. Class 2 is an object that also takes in an argument of another object from class 3 (not shown):

```
public class class2 {

    public static class2 task3 (int k) {
        // uses k to do something, the end goal of this question
    } 

}
```

Please let me know if you need any more information. I am relatively new to OOP, so please bear with me and correct me if I am not using it correctly.

Comment: What's the problem here, I don't see issue rather than variable shadowing

Comment: No issue here `class2.task3(k);` What is the problem you are facing? You are able to access members of `class2` there.

Comment: Within class2.task3, I want to access k from class1 without passing it through task 1, and task 2. How can I make it visible to class2?

Comment: How can I make the code work without variable shadowing? Will that fix the problem of k not being updated if I only use it as an argument for class2.task3?

Comment: Please read the [Java Tutorial titled Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) and pay special attention to the section named "Passing Primitive Data Type Arguments". Also take a look at this [tutorial on getters and setters](https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices)

Comment: Thank you for the info on passing primitive data types. I see now that the updated value of k will only exist inside the methods it is passed.
However, if I set a setter and getter for k in class 1, I cannot use it in class 2, because I cannot import class1 like I imported class2-- I think this is because class1 is inside (default package) in Eclipse.